# Is there any kind of annotations like the ones in Java for swift?

Tags: java, swift, dependency-injection

I was looking for some dependency injection framework for swift(found some: [Cleanse](https://github.com/square/Cleanse), [Dip](https://github.com/AliSoftware/Dip), [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject), [Typhoon](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon)) but they don't have what I'm looking for(they only work like: `container.getInstance(Class)`).

I was looking for something to use DI in constructors, like in java:

```
property1;
contructor(property1){
 this.property1 = property1;
}
```

**Is there any way to do this in swift?**

Is very useful for testing and decoupling

thanks

Comment: "Attributes provide more information about a declaration or type".

This is not related at all with DI

Answer (score 0):

I recently pre-released Weaver, a dependency injection framework which allows you to inject dependencies by annotating your code (https://github.com/scribd/Weaver)

For example, you can do things like this:

```
final class MoviesViewController: UIViewController {

    private let dependencies: MoviesViewControllerDependencyResolver

    private var movies = [Movie]()

    // weaver: movieManager <- MovieManaging
    // ^ this is how you inject movieManager

    required init(injecting dependencies: MoviesViewControllerDependencyResolver) {
        self.dependencies = dependencies
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This is how you access to movieManager.
        dependencies.movieManager.getMovies { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let page):
                self.movies = page.results
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            case .failure(let error):
                self.showError(error)
            }
        }
    }

    // ... 
}
```